# zookeeper - Force Leader election

Tags: apache-zookeeper

We are having 5 EC2 instances and running zookeeper in cluster mode. Below are the zookeeper status. I want to force setup to Server1 as a Leader if server3 is done. **Is it possible?**

- Server1 - follower
- Server2 - follower
- Server3 - Leader
- Server4 - follower
- Server5 - follower

Thanks.